# Search for an item in multiple Lua lists

Tags: lua

I'm working on a script right now and have encountered a roadblock where I can't quite figure out how to check if a value is in any of the selected tables in Lua.

Example script of the problem below.

```lua
players = {213, 644}
helpers = {632, 965}

-- How would I check if a number (for example 632) was in either of these two tables?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this simple table find value `_v`:

```lua
local players = {213, 644}
local helpers = {632, 965}

local function find(t, _v)
    for i, v in pairs(t) do
        local type1 = type(v)
        if type1 == 'table' then
            local value = { find(v, _v) }
            if #value ~= 0 then
                table.insert(value, 2, i)
                return unpack(value)
            end
        elseif i == _v or v == _v then
            return i, v
        end
    end
end

-- Example:
print(find(players, 632) and 'Was finded in table: players') -- nil
print(find(helpers, 632) and 'Was finded in table: helpers') -- 'Was finded...'
```

Answer (score 0):

To check wether a value is in a list you need to traverse over that list and compare each element with the value you're looking for.
If you want to do this for multiple lists you need to do this for each of the lists.

```
local lists = {players, helpers}
local foundIn = {}

for _, list in ipairs(lists) do
  for _, v in pairs(list) do
    if v == 632 then
      table.insert(foundIn, list)
      break
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If the tables are static or do not change frequently, try this:

```
players = {213, 644}
helpers = {632, 965}
present = {}

for k,v in pairs(players) do present[v]=true end
for k,v in pairs(helpers) do present[v]=true end

print(present[632])
print(present[633])
```

If you need to know where an item was found, do this:

```
for k,v in pairs(players) do present[v]="players" end
for k,v in pairs(helpers) do present[v]="helpers" end

print(present[632])
print(present[644])
```